Does this hypergeometric function have a closed-form or special value？
$$_{3}F_{2}(1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};z) $$
I don't know much about hypergeometric functions, and I'm not sure if it has a closed-form or special value.

Where did you come across this particular hypergeometric function?

@Arthur wolfram solves ODEs internally in terms of hypergeometric functions

@Arthur This result comes from the integral $$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{kK^{'} }{1-k^{2}z }\mathrm{d}k$$ $$K^{'} =K(\sqrt{1-k^{2} } )$$ K is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind
